# I need to get the value from Nested Property 

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to get the value from nested property.

In MainClass i have a Students Property which is Type of Student Class.

```
MainClass obj = new MainClass ();

obj.Name = "XII";
obj.Students = new List<Students>()
    {
        new Students() { ID = "a0", Name = "A" },
        new Bridge() { ID = "a1", Name = "B" }
    };

Type t = Type.GetType(obj.ToString());
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("Students");

object gg = p.GetValue(obj, null);
var hh = gg.GetType();
string propertyType = string.Empty;

if (hh.IsGenericType)
    {
        string[] propertyTypes = hh.ToString().Split('[');
        Type gggg = Type.GetType(propertyTypes[1].Remove(propertyTypes[1].Length - 1));
        foreach (PropertyInfo pro in gggg.GetProperties())
             {
                 if (pro.Name.Equals("Name"))
                 {
                     // Get the value here
                 }
             }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the `Find` method of the List ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? and is reflection really neccessary? what is the `Bridge` class for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

```
Type t = Type.GetType(obj.ToString());
```

is wrong. This only works if a class has not overloaded the ToString() method, and will fall at runtime if it has. Fortunately, every class has a GetType() metod (it's defined on object, so `Type t = obj.GetType()` is the correct code.

Second, the

```
string[] propertyTypes = hh.ToString().Split('[');
Type gggg = Type.GetType(propertyTypes[1].Remove(propertyTypes[1].Length - 1)
```

is an awful way to get the type the specified the generic type, as there is a method `GetGenericArguments` that does that for you, so this code could be changed with

```
Type[] genericArguments = hh.GetGenericArguments();
Type gggg = genericArguments[0];
```

And now to the real problem, accessing an list item. The best way to do that is to use the indexer (`[]`)  of the `List<>` class. In c# when you define an indexer, it's automatically transfered to a property called `Item`, and we can use that property to extract our values (the `Item` name can be inferred from the type definition, but for the most part, that can be hardcoded)

```
PropertyInfo indexer = hh.GetProperty("Item");  // gets the indexer

//note the second parameter, that's the index
object student1 = indexer.GetValue(gg, new object[]{0}); 
object student2 = indexer.GetValue(gg, new object[]{1}); 

PropertyInfo name = gggg.GetProperty("Name");
object studentsName1 = name.GetValue(student1, null); // returns "A"
object studentsName2 = name.GetValue(student2, null); // returns "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `Equals` method for both `Students` and `Bridge` class then use `Find` or use `LINQ`

Comment: Actually that is incorrect. `Type.GetType` expects the name of a class, and then returns the type for that string, so your second line wont compile (in general). The first line is sintaxically correct, but silly, because the class could have overriden the `ToString()` method, and `obj.GetType()` is the short and correct version.

Comment: Thanks Sweko !. I am new to C# world thats why i coded like that.. I learned something new from you.. thanks again.